# Can I use the component of One Application into another Application?

Tags: angular

I want to use the component of one application in to another. Suppose A1 is part of Application A.

I want use this A1 component in another application B.

Is this possible in angular 5?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem

During development, you can just add the "component A1" in "application B" by referring to it (by a file path) in component and module... At build time, it will be part of the built packages..

Comment: By adding the component in main module it gives me error something like this:ERROR in ../gic/node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject' in '/Users/exsete/Desktop/Exsete/gic/node_modules/@angular/router/esm5'
ERROR in ../gic/node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/Users/exsete/Desktop/Exsete/gic/node_modules/@angular/common/esm5'

Comment: to add a component, you just need to add it by referring to the exact ts file by its file path- same for adding it in your module; are you using this component as a route in your application?

Comment: when you do import of componentA1 in the module.ts of your applicationB... you didn't get any errors, right?.... once the component is imported, it would then be added to the appRoutes which you define in your "RouterModule.forRoot"

Comment: route is defined in another module app-route.module.ts. i am giving the exact file location while importing the file but its gives me same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use NRWL workspace to share code between two apps, by pushing sharable code in a separate library. Please refer nrwl.io for more.